# How is the arm memory model different from ia64?

Tags: architecture, arm, itanium

I have to deal with a lot of multithreaded programming at work.  Specifically, I want to know how the ARM memory model differs from IA64.  Both are very weak models, but are there any specific differences that I should know about?  I'm familiar with ia64, not with arm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same question, and while I haven't completely found the answer, this paper might be useful: [Reasoning about the ARM weakly consistent memory model](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1353528)

In the Further Work section, it seems to imply that no one (even at ARM, since they wrote the paper) has answered the question formally:

> ... there are several completeness
>   questions we need to answer. How does
>   the axiomatic model fit in with the
>   operational one? ... And what is the
>   precise embedding of the ARM model
>   into Alpha, Intel, JMM?

**Update:** Also look at [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.07.23a.pdf) by Paul McKenney. It discusses the types of memory access reordering that various processors do and what instructions are available to fence the accesses. In particular, note Table 5 on page 16 that summarizes the allowed reorderings for each architecture. ARMv7, IA64, POWER, and SPARC RMO all share the same characteristics, namely, that without a barrier, anything except dependent loads can be reordered.

Comment: The mention of Intel in that paper is almost certainly referring to x86, not Itanium.  But yes, in general comparing the ARM model to others isn't a solved problem (or wasn't when that was written.)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering might answer your question. From the table it shows, it seems ARMv7 has the same as IA64.